# Two MYSQL tables with same data has different sizes

Tags: mysql

Please find the below 'test' table structure and it has 5566 rows.
[image: test_table_structure]

Please find the explained details for below query:

```
select * from test where sig_date='2014-03-15' and symbol='AXP' order by score;
```

[image: test_table_explain]

I created same structure table with different name and with composite PRIMARY KEY and inserted the same data which exists in 'test' table.
[image: test_com_indx_strcture]

Now explained the query and it selecting only 9 records:

```
select * from test_com_indx where sig_date='2014-03-15' and symbol='AXP' order by score;
```

[image: test_with_composite_index]

when i checked the 2 table sizes, test_com_indx occupies more space and both tables has same data.
[image: table_space_details]

My belief is, as 'test' table has PRIMARY KEY as id, the data is stored phisically in the order of id.
and in 'test_com_indx' table, data is stored phisically in the order of composite PRIMARY KEY.So, there is no separate copy of index for both tables
and both tables should have same size.

Please correct me if my assumption is wrong and why both tables have different size?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How much space is "more space"?

Comment: Please check the details i added in question

Comment: is it have same rows total? `select count(*) from test` `select count(*) from test_com_indx` ?

Comment: yes both has 5566 row count

Comment: Are you sure? I saw 3306 in `test_com_indx` in your small picture or problem with my eyes???

Comment: yes, when i quired both tables i am getting same count

Comment: are you saying this image wrong? http://i.stack.imgur.com/w0LnD.png If yes, case closed. You didn't even have `id` in `test_com_indx` and have different size in `symbol` and `symbol_member` which maybe some characters missing also primary key have different constraint. I don't know how you can assume they will give you same size.

Comment: In that case test_com_indx should occupy less space but its taking more that 'test' table.

Comment: What program are you using to check the table sizes, what version of MySQL is this and one what Operating System is the server?  And could you please update the screenshots so the two tables have the same number of rows?  Otherwise the answer is they don't have "the same data", case closed.

Comment: [According to the InnoDB docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-restrictions.html), "*InnoDB does not keep an internal count of rows in a table because concurrent transactions might “see” different numbers of rows at the same time.*"  I guess that accounts for why TABLE_ROWS is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Doing some reading, the results from `information_schema.TABLES` can get out of sync with reality which would explain why your TABLE_ROWS are different.  Running `ANALYZE TABLE test, test_com_indx` may bring them into sync.

If the sizes remain different after that, either I'm wrong about ANALYZE fixing the problem, or its because of these differences in your schema.

- test_com_indx is using `VARCHAR(10)`, test has `VARCHAR(25)`.
- test has an extra INTEGER id column and has to track AUTOCOMMIT.
- test_com_indx has a complex primary key.

Or/and its because there's *no guarantee* about how the internals work even if you do the exact same thing twice.  SQL databases are declarative, you're not supposed to know how it answers your queries, which frees up the server to do whatever is most efficient.  There are many reasons why this might be so...

- The order of INSERTs can change how the data is stored.
- The indexes can change how the data is stored.
- [InnoDB does not store one table per file](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-table-and-index.html).  It's all mixed up in a tablespace.  A change in one table can alter the internal storage of another.